# Trying to understand what "theme="[object Object]" " means when using Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I's seeing this code rendered in several elements. They render properly, but the code looks strange.

Code lookis like this:

```
<a theme="[object Object]" class="sc-fAjcbJ eHVIJQ" href="/">Inicio</a>
```

Could you help me to understand why is this? As I said, the element is rendered properly.

Comment: `<a theme={JSON.stringify([object Object])} class="sc-fAjcbJ eHVIJQ" href="/">Inicio</a>`

Comment: Most likely because the code is written wrong. Might help to see the actual code that’s producing this